# Showing the result of loop but repeating the value

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have question about loopings. The value of my loop are **from.text = 1**, **too.text = 2** and **perfloor.text = 2**. My problem is when im showing the value of X the result is `1,2,1,2` but i want is `1,2,3,4` I also add the **count** variable to +1 the value of X but nothing happens.

```
For i As Integer = from.Text To too.Text 'first loop value from from.text and too.text
 For x As Integer = from.Text To perfloor.Text 'second loop value of from.text and perfloor.text
    Dim count As Integer 
    count = x + 1
     MsgBox(x)
 next
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment your count as `count = count + 1` and then output `count` variable rather than `x` as `x` is a loop variable.

Declare your counter variable `count` at the top so that it has the scope to increment

```
Dim count As Integer 
For i As Integer = from.Text To too.Text 'first loop value from from.text and too.text
 For x As Integer = from.Text To perfloor.Text 'second loop value of from.text and perfloor.text
    count = count + 1
     MsgBox(count)
 next
next
```